# How do I drop this database in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: database list]

One of my tables got corrupted somehow and I can't seem to drop the whole schema. I have been trying to drop this database but I have been facing with lots of errors. I have tried dropping from MySQL workbench , dropping from PHPMyAdmin.

I expect the schema, `gs` to be dropped

Comment: `REPAIR TABLE ...`

Comment: What kind of errors did you get? Please post the exact error text (preferably no pictures).

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response. I am unsure if its due to the corrupted database but I have tried the following methods:

- Dropping the table
- Truncate the table
- Dropping the schema

Here are some of the error messages i have been getting
- Error Code: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query
- Error Code: 1709. Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.

Comment: Error Code: 1709. Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
'gs.stock_info', 'repair', 'Error', 'Table \'gs.stock_info\' doesn\'t exist'
'gs.stock_info', 'repair', 'error', 'Corrupt'